# Desktop loads, but no dash. Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, 15.04

This all originated when I installed Nvidia drivers from terminal using the xorg edgers PPA.

I have since uninstalled them, but that did not help much.

I can't even open terminal unless it is with ctrl+alt+f7.

I have tried forcing compizconfig to load from a similar question I found, but even after turning the unity plugin on nothing loaded.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How did you install the driver (exact command) ? Is that normal ubuntu with unity desktop ? Window decorations look different, What is the exact model of your graphics card and is it a laptop or PC ? Make a better screen shot, press `print screen` on your keyboard, upload it, give me the link and I will edit it in

Comment: I have a 60% keyboard so I can't prnt screen, but even if I could I have no way to upload it. I can't access google chrome or anything. *don't have a button for just print screen, and the multi button commands don't work atm.

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings.

Comment: What model GPU ? Issue may be the edgers paa, remove it like this `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && apt-get update` then use the version that comes with ubuntu, open terminal and just run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates` reboot like this `sudo reboot`

Comment: Oh oops, I thought I had already said it. I am using a gt 610.

Comment: I tried the order of commands you listed, but it sent me back to where the problem originated. I am going to uninstall the drivers completely, as it is the closest I've come to fixing it. The issue now is that when booting from grub an error pops up saying something about "512" and bad usbs.

Comment: Uninstall the drivers completely in one command `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` Now does it work without a driver ?

Comment: Nope. It's the same thing :/

Comment: Have you tried this in terminal `rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1` from what I assume is the answer you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: Also try this `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic && apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ctrl+alt+f2 for a terminal, then login

now type:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

then:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

lastly:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

This is how to manually restart the display manager. Let us know if this helps.